# More than one value for properties (multiple values)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to assign, for example, more then one responsible person to a task.

I thought to use [properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html#Property-Syntax) like

```
:PROPERTIES:
:RESPONSIBLE: Kate
:RESPONSIBLE+: Aaron
:END:
```

But my agenda search for `RESPONSIBLE="Aaron"` has no results.

One reason not to use tags is, I can easily search for tasks without a responsible person, if the values were numbers, I could use operators like `>` and it does not clutter the headings with a lot of tags.

Is there a way to do this with properties?

Or is there a different way to make agenda search include, e. g., a todo with multiple responsible persons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property values are strings. The value of the property `RESPONSIBLE` above is  the string `"Kate Aaron"`, so your search does not find it. You could do a regular expression search instead: `RESPONSIBLE={Aaron}` (see [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) for details).

IMO however, you are better off using tags. Given headlines like this:

```
* TODO Something       :Kate:Aaron:
  ...

* TODO Something else
```

you can do `C-c a m +Aaron` to find headlines tagged with `Aaron` and you can find unassigned headlines with `C-c a m TAGS=""` - this is using the fact that Org recognizes [Special properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties).